# Where does Prometheus store metrics data (in container)?

Tags: docker, prometheus

I am searching for the `./data` folder described in [Storage section pf Prometheus Documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#on-disk-layout).
I run a basic Prometheus Docker container `prom/prometheus` on Kubernetes. If I execute a shell inside the container, the working directory is `/prometheus` and it contains the `wal` directory, but it does not have the structure mentioned in the documentation and I can not find any metric data.

Where are the metrics stored which I can query over Prometheus GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the problem now. The structure, which was mentioned in the documentation, need several hours to build up.

```
./data
├── 01BKGTZQ1HHWHV8FBJXW1Y3W0K
│   └── meta.json
├── 01BKGV7JC0RY8A6MACW02A2PJD
│   ├── chunks
│   │   └── 000001
│   ├── tombstones
│   ├── index
│   └── meta.json
└── wal
    ├── 00000002
    └── checkpoint.000001
```

The first of those folders starting with `01...` appeared after 4 hours. The next one took an other 2 hours. It seems to vary according to the amount of metrics you are pulling.

---

Sidenote: As nischay goyal wrote in his answer, Prometheus TSDB can not be decoded. You can [query the Prometheus API with a script to export metrics](https://medium.com/@aneeshputtur/export-data-from-prometheus-to-csv-b19689d780aa).

Comment: Where can you find the ./data directory? I can't seem to find it on my Prometheus server.

Comment: @fuzzi usually it's just under  `/prometheus/data`. Maybe you have the same problem I had and you just need to wait some time until enough data has been collected.

Comment: This is unfortunately not surfaced in prometheus docs, but if you wanted to know how WAL stores data the [README file](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/8d8be43824b3e039f2f6d0735ead572bc6270a5a/tsdb/docs/format/wal.md) in prometheus source might help.

Answer (score 3):

As you can check the Prometheus `Dockerfile` on Github (https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/Dockerfile#L24), the working directory is `/prometheus` and that where you will find all the metrics and data.

Below is the data present in `/prometheus` directory

```
/prometheus $ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nogroup          0 May 28 12:39 lock
-rw-r--r--    1 nobody   nogroup      20001 May 28 12:45 queries.active
drwxr-xr-x    2 nobody   nogroup       4096 May 28 12:39 wal
```

And this is the *Time Series Database * which you can't decode . If you will run more exporters, probably you can see more folders like `chunks` etc.

> Ref: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/1.8/storage/

Comment: Like I said, I can not find the data **INSIDE** this folder. There is only the `/prometheus/wal` folder, and inside this folder there is only one file called `00000000` which contains byte, but I don't how to open it.

Comment: First of all,  prometheus needs to pull the metrics. then only you can see data

Comment: I can query metrics over the web frontend and with Grafana, so Prometheus already pulled metrics.

Comment: Edited my answer, that's the Time series database , which is prometheus functionality. Decoding that is to understand how Prometheus DB works.

Comment: Can you please check this and close?

Answer (score 1):

if you run docker exec containerid , then you would see it /prometheus/data
to have persistent data mount with local volume if on laptop or use network storage on aws